# two equal signs in php when NOT comparing

Tags: php, syntax

What do the two equal signs mean when not being used to compare?

```
$saveOrder  = $listOrder == 'a.ordering';
```

I've never seen anything like this in php.... I am looking at the weblinks Joomla 1.7 admin component.

Thanks

Comment: What makes you think it's not being used to compare? It looks to me like an assignment to the `$saveOrder` variable of the boolean result of comparing `$listOrder` to `'a.ordering'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** used for comparing. Except **the result of the comparison is assigned to `$saveOrder`**.

The following code:

```
<?php

list($listOrder1, $listOrder2) = array('a.ordering', 'a.something_else');

$saveOrder1  = $listOrder1 == 'a.ordering';
$saveOrder2  = $listOrder2 == 'a.ordering';
```

assigns `true` to the `$saveOrder1` variable and `false` to the `$saveOrder2` variable. If you do not believe, [check for yourself here](http://ideone.com/nUQb9).

Answer (score 1):

They are comparing. It's just not wrapped in parenthesis (like a comparison expression with `if`/`while`/etc).

`$saveOrder` will be assigned either `true` or `false` (the result of the condition).

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is the same as `$saveOrder  = ($listOrder == 'a.ordering');`

Answer (score 0):

In your statement also the double equal sign(==) used for the comparison purpose only. Actually your statement contains both the 'assignment'(=) and 'comparison'(==) operators which leads to your confusion.

That is equivalent to `$saveOrder = ($listOrder == 'a.ordering');`, so first compares the $listOrder with 'a.ordering' and assign the result(true or false) to $saveOrder.

Hope this clear you confusion, if not let me know once.

Answer (score 0):

```
$listOrder1='a.ordering';
$listOrder1='wrong'
$saveOrder1  = $listOrder1 == 'a.ordering';//1
$saveOrder2  = $listOrder2 == 'a.ordering';//
```

You can see the output when printing the first will be `1` whereas the second will return: (i.e. nothing)